# How to deserialize json without key value pair? C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, key-value

I get the following JSON data from JSON endpoint API's which I can't change:

```
[
  [
    "NameA",
    [
      "AAA"
    ]
  ],
  [
    "NameB",
    [
      "BBB"
    ]
  ],
  [
    "NameC",
    [
      "CCC"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I know its a valid JSON. Though I am not able to parse it in C#. I tried to generate the class for this JSON using online tools but it did not help. Any help would be appreciated as I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: What is the expected results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MessagePack via Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MessagePack/).

CLASS OBJECTS

```
[MessagePackObject]
public class Item1
{
    [Key(0)]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [Key(1)]
    public Item2 Value { get; set; }
}

[MessagePackObject]
public class Item2
{
    [Key(0)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

SERIALIZATION

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");
var byteArray = MessagePackSerializer.ConvertFromJson(json);
var itemList = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<List<Item1>>(byteArray);
```

OUTPUT
[image]

Comment: Thanks @tontonsevilla I was not aware of MessagePack via Nuget. This should solve it.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately got stuck on following error:
FormatterNotRegisteredException: ElementsListContainer is not registered in resolver: MessagePack.Resolvers.StandardResolver